# FTP with progress bar using Util.copyStream - JAVA

Tags: java, upload, ftp

I'm using Util.copyStream() to upload a file via FTP. It shows the progress on the progressBar, but when I try to see the file via FTP Client (e.g. FileZilla), it's not there. Can anyone help me?

This is the FTPUpload Class:

```
    package restrictedareamanager;

    import java.awt.HeadlessException;
    import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
    import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
    import org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamAdapter;
    import org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamEvent;
    import org.apache.commons.net.io.CopyStreamListener;
    import org.apache.commons.net.io.Util;

    public class FTPUploader extends SwingWorker <Object,Object> {

        private String servidor;
        private String usuario;
        private String senha;
        private String titulo;
        private String subtitulo;
        private File dest;

    public FTPUploader (String servidor, String usuario, String senha, String titulo, String subtitulo, File dest) {

        this.servidor = servidor;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.titulo = titulo;
        this.subtitulo = subtitulo;
        this.dest = dest;

    }   

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient ();
    final ProgressBar bar = ProgressBar.getInstancia();   

                try {  
                 ftp.connect(servidor);  

                 //verifica se conectou com sucesso!  
                 if( FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion( ftp.getReplyCode() ) ) {  
                     ftp.login (usuario, senha);  
                 } else {  
                     //erro ao se conectar  
                     ftp.disconnect();  
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao se conectar com o servidor FTP", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);    
                     System.exit(1);  
                 }  

                     ftp.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                     ftp.changeWorkingDirectory("/download");
                     ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(this.titulo);
                     ftp.changeWorkingDirectory (this.subtitulo);

                     bar.setLabel1("Sending " + dest.getName());
                     bar.setLabel2("To " + this.servidor + "/download" + "/" + titulo + "/" + subtitulo);
                     bar.setLabel3 ("Progress: ");

                     OutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(ftp.storeFileStream(dest.getName().toString()));
                     CopyStreamListener listener = new CopyStreamListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void bytesTransferred(final long totalBytesTransferred, final int bytesTransferred, final long streamSize) {
                            setProgress((int) Math.round(((double) totalBytesTransferred / (double) streamSize) * 100d));
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void bytesTransferred(CopyStreamEvent arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            }

                      };

                        Util.copyStream(new FileInputStream(dest), output , ftp.getBufferSize(), dest.length(), listener);
                        //ftp.storeFile (dest.getName(), new FileInputStream (dest.getPath().toString()));
                        ftp.logout();
                        ftp.disconnect(); 

                 } catch( IOException | HeadlessException e ) {  
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocorreu um erro ao enviar o arquivo.", "Erro", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);  
                     System.exit(1);
                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     System.out.println (e.toString());
                 }


       bar.dispose();
       return null;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "the file"? When are you looking?

Comment: Did you try actually closing the streams?

Comment: chrylis It's not in the directory that it should be.
@MadProgrammer Yes, I tried to. Btw, the ftp.storeFile works just fine, but that doesn't update the progressBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavaDocs for `storeFileStream` say that you have to close the stream when you are done. I dont you doing that. That might be a good place to start. Other than being quite verbose, your code looks pretty solid.

I dont use a listener or a stream, but I use this code all the time to send a file using FTP and it works.

Note that `ftp` is an instance of `FTPClient`

```
/**
 * Transmits a file to the FTP server
 * @param filePath The location on the server to place the file
 * @param data The contents of the file
 * @return True if the operation completes successfully, false otherwise
 */
public boolean send(String filePath, byte[] data)
{
    if(isConnected() == false)
    {
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Attempting operation when not connected to FTP Server");
        return false;
    }

    try 
    {
        boolean success =  ftp.storeFile(filePath, new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        if(success)
        {
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Succesfully transmitted file: " + filePath);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not transmit file: " + filePath);
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, getLastReply());
            return false;
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not transmit file: " + filePath, ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! Tried to close the streams, but still not working. You are using the ftp.storeFile () function, but I can't update the progressBar using this function, so I must implement the Util.copyStream (), or another one...